# Solving an equation in matlab

Tags: matlab

I would like to solve the equation:

```
1/2*logninv(x, 0.03-1/2*0.2^2 + log(100), 0.2^2) +1/2*logninv(x, 0.03-1/2*0.1^2 + log(100), 0.1^2) == 100
```

I can solve this using excel with the solver, but I'm trying to solve it with matlab, I use the code:

```
vpasolve(1/2*logninv(x, 0.03-1/2*0.2^2 + log(100), 0.2^2) +1/2*logninv(x, 0.03-1/2*0.1^2 + log(100), 0.1^2) == 100,x,0.24)
```

but this gives me following error:

```
Error using symfun>validateArgNames (line 175)
Second input must be a scalar or vector of unique symbolic variables.

Error in symfun (line 42)
            y.vars = validateArgNames(inputs);

Error in sym/subsasgn (line 1452)
                C = symfun(B,[inds{:}]);

Error in logninv (line 60)
p(p < 0 | 1 < p) = NaN;
```

from which I deduce that I need to tell matlab that x must be between 0 and 1 so then I use:

```
vpasolve(1/2*logninv(x, 0.03-1/2*0.2^2 + log(100), 0.2^2) +1/2*logninv(x, 0.03-1/2*0.1^2 + log(100), 0.1^2) == 100,x<1,x>0,[x])
```

but this gives me the error:

```
Error using symfun>validateArgNames (line 175)
Second input must be a scalar or vector of unique symbolic variables.

Error in symfun (line 42)
            y.vars = validateArgNames(inputs);

Error in sym/subsasgn (line 1452)
                C = symfun(B,[inds{:}]);

Error in logninv (line 60)
p(p < 0 | 1 < p) = NaN;
```

Comment: How do you deduce that? The error message says "Second input must be a scalar or vector of unique symbolic variables."

Comment: And your second syntax is not correct. To pass multiple equations, make a vector of equations.

Comment: I thought "p(p < 0 | 1 < p)" meant this..

Comment: Maybe you are right. I fiddled around a bit, but couldn't find a solution. Do you need VPA?

Comment: Ok, I found that that line makes a problem because at one point `p` is not a numeric array but a symbol. I suspect `logninv` is not compatible with symbolic computation, and therefore with `vpasolve`. Again, do you need VPA, or would a standard-precision numerical estimate be OK too?

Comment: a standard-precision numerical estimate would be OK :) (I don't know what VPA is but I'm pretty sure that I don't need it ;) )

Comment: Then why did you use `vpasolve`? VPA is variable precision arithmetic, and it is a way to get higher numerical precision than with standard `double` variables.

Comment: I used vpasolve because I tried solve first and that didn't work (this is the first time I try to solve something like this using matlab)

Comment: (as you could probably deduce from my ignorance)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to find the position within an interval at which a function attains a specific value. This can be framed as an optimization problem: Where is the deviation of the function value from the specific value minimal? Since the variable is bounded to an interval, we can use [`fminbnd`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fminbnd.html) from the *Optimization Toolbox*.

Define the function:

```
fun = @(x)(1/2*logninv(x, 0.03-1/2*0.2^2 + log(100), 0.2^2) +1/2*logninv(x, 0.03-1/2*0.1^2 + log(100), 0.1^2));
```

Define a function that computes the deviation or error:

```
err = @(x)(abs(fun(x) - 100));
```

Solve the optimization problem:

```
x = fminbnd(err, 0, 1)
```

The result is 0.23993814958158.

Let's check whether the error could be brought down to zero:

```
err(x)
```

The result is 0.000121288471035541. Considering that the function value goes from 0 at 0 to 110 at 0.99, that is an acceptable precision.

If necessary, the precision can be increased by setting `TolX` and possibly other options via [`optimset`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/optimset.html):

```
x = fminbnd(err, 0, 1, optimset('TolX', 1e-8))
```

Now the result is 0.239922902427111, and the remaining error is 1.49937875448813 · 10<sup>-8</sup>.

Note that `TolX` specifies the precision to which $x$ is estimated, not the acceptable size of the remaining error. The default value is `1e-4`.

Comment: awesome, thanks man! I had never heard of "fminbnd" but it's perfect :D!

Comment: Right, forgot about that :)!